# How do I have vim complete scan all files in the current directory

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I have my complete option set to:

set complete=.,w,b,u,t,i

Is there another option I can use to have it scan the current directory (all files) for completion?

Also, is there a way to complete 2 lines when the text matches the first line?